# update group prices from CSV file

Tags: magento-1.9, group-price

I am trying to update group prices programmatically, my prices come from a CSV file, The error I am getting is

Fatal error: Call to a member function setData() on a non-object in /chroot/home/radmodne/radmod.net/html/import_attribute.php on line 129

I have put together this script from others I found online, what it does it update all prices and qty based on an attribute.   This part this working fine, what doesn't work is updating the group prices part I just added. I suspect the default magento functions are not included which is causing my issue, but i don't know for sure.

```
$mageFilename = 'app/Mage.php';
require_once $mageFilename;
Mage::setIsDeveloperMode(true);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
umask(0);
Mage::app('admin');
Mage::register('isSecureArea', 1);
Mage::app()->setCurrentStore(Mage_Core_Model_App::ADMIN_STORE_ID);

set_time_limit(0);
ini_set('memory_limit','1024M');

/***************** UTILITY FUNCTIONS ********************/
function _getConnection($type = 'core_read'){
    return Mage::getSingleton('core/resource')->getConnection($type);
}

function _getTableName($tableName){
    return Mage::getSingleton('core/resource')->getTableName($tableName);
}

function _getAttributeId($attribute_code = 'price'){
    $connection = _getConnection('core_read');
    $sql = "SELECT attribute_id
                FROM " . _getTableName('eav_attribute') . "
            WHERE
                entity_type_id = ?
                AND attribute_code = ?";
    $entity_type_id = _getEntityTypeId();
    return $connection->fetchOne($sql, array($entity_type_id, $attribute_code));
}

function _getEntityTypeId($entity_type_code = 'catalog_product'){
    $connection = _getConnection('core_read');
    $sql        = "SELECT entity_type_id FROM " . _getTableName('eav_entity_type') . " WHERE entity_type_code = ?";
    return $connection->fetchOne($sql, array($entity_type_code));
}



function _checkIfSkuExists($sku){
    $connection = _getConnection('core_read');
    $sql        = "SELECT COUNT(*) AS count_no FROM " . _getTableName('catalog_product_entity_varchar') . " WHERE value = ?";
    $count      = $connection->fetchOne($sql, array($sku));
    if($count > 0){
        return true;
    }else{
        return false;
    }
}

function _getIdFromSku($sku){
    $connection = _getConnection('core_read');
    $sql        = "SELECT entity_id FROM " . _getTableName('catalog_product_entity_varchar') . " WHERE value = ?";
    return $connection->fetchOne($sql, array($sku));
}

function _updateStocks($data){
    $connection     = _getConnection('core_write');
    $sku            = $data[0];
    $newQty         = $data[1];
    //$productId      = _getIdFromSku($sku);
    $attributeId    = _getAttributeId();


    $sql_prod        = "SELECT entity_id FROM " . _getTableName('catalog_product_entity_varchar') . " WHERE value = $sku";
    $sqlQuery = $connection->query($sql_prod);
    while ($row = $sqlQuery->fetch() ) {
    $entity_id = $row['entity_id'];

    $sql            = "UPDATE " . _getTableName('cataloginventory_stock_item') . " csi,
                       " . _getTableName('cataloginventory_stock_status') . " css
                       SET
                       csi.qty = ?,
                       csi.is_in_stock = ?,
                       css.qty = ?,
                       css.stock_status = ?
                       WHERE
                       csi.product_id = ?
                       AND csi.product_id = css.product_id";
    $isInStock      = $newQty > 0 ? 1 : 0;
    $stockStatus    = $newQty > 0 ? 1 : 0;
    $connection->query($sql, array($newQty, $isInStock, $newQty, $stockStatus, $entity_id));


    }


}

function _updatePrices($data){
    $connection     = _getConnection('core_write');
    $sku            = $data[0];
    $newPrice       = $data[5];

     $newPrice1       = $data[2];
     $newPrice2       = $data[3];
     $newPrice4       = $data[4];
     $newPrice5       = $data[6];


    //$productId      = _getIdFromSku($sku);
    $attributeId    = _getAttributeId();

    $sql_prod        = "SELECT entity_id FROM " . _getTableName('catalog_product_entity_varchar') . " WHERE value = $sku";
    $sqlQuery = $connection->query($sql_prod);


    while ($row = $sqlQuery->fetch() ) {
        $entity_id = $row['entity_id'];

        $sql = "UPDATE " . _getTableName('catalog_product_entity_decimal') . " cped
                    SET  cped.value = ?
                WHERE  cped.attribute_id = ?
                AND cped.entity_id = ?";
        $connection->query($sql, array($newPrice, $attributeId, $entity_id));


            $entity_id->setData('group_price',array());
            $entity_id->save();

            $g_PricingData = array (
              array ('website_id'=>0, 'cust_group'=>5, 'price'=>$newPrice1),
              array ('website_id'=>0, 'cust_group'=>6, 'price'=>$newPrice2),
              array ('website_id'=>0, 'cust_group'=>7, 'price'=>$newPrice4),
              array ('website_id'=>0, 'cust_group'=>8, 'price'=>$newPrice5)
             );
            $entity_id->setData('group_price',$g_PricingData);
            $entity_id->save();



    }



}
```

The code that its causing the issues is in my _updatePrices function

```
$entity_id->setData('group_price',array());
        $entity_id->save();

        $g_PricingData = array (
          array ('website_id'=>0, 'cust_group'=>5, 'price'=>$newPrice1),
          array ('website_id'=>0, 'cust_group'=>6, 'price'=>$newPrice2),
          array ('website_id'=>0, 'cust_group'=>7, 'price'=>$newPrice4),
          array ('website_id'=>0, 'cust_group'=>8, 'price'=>$newPrice5)
         );
        $entity_id->setData('group_price',$g_PricingData);
        $entity_id->save();
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so this is a very hacky way to do it, but it works (i have 4 group prices). If someone can provide a better answer I am open to it.

With some data mining I found the group prices were stored in 4 tables, so i update all 4, with all 4 of my group prices..

```
    /*  catalog_product_entity_group_price table */
    $sql_price_one = "UPDATE " . _getTableName('catalog_product_entity_group_price') . " cpegp 
                SET  cpegp.value = ?
                WHERE  cpegp.customer_group_id = ?
                AND cpegp.entity_id = ?";
    $connection->query($sql_price_one, array($newPrice1, 5, $entity_id));

    $sql_price_two = "UPDATE " . _getTableName('catalog_product_entity_group_price') . "  cpegp
                SET  cpegp.value = ?
                WHERE  cpegp.customer_group_id = ?
                AND cpegp.entity_id = ?";
    $connection->query($sql_price_two, array($newPrice2, 6, $entity_id));

    $sql_price_four = "UPDATE " . _getTableName('catalog_product_entity_group_price') . " cpegp 
                SET  cpegp.value = ?
                WHERE  cpegp.customer_group_id = ?
                AND cpegp.entity_id = ?";
    $connection->query($sql_price_four, array($newPrice4, 7, $entity_id));

    $sql_price_five = "UPDATE " . _getTableName('catalog_product_entity_group_price') . " cpegp 
                SET  cpegp.value = ?
                WHERE  cpegp.customer_group_id = ?
                AND cpegp.entity_id = ?";
    $connection->query($sql_price_five, array($newPrice5, 8, $entity_id));


    /*  catalog_product_index_group_price table */

    $sql_price_one = "UPDATE " . _getTableName('catalog_product_index_group_price') . " cpigp 
                SET  cpigp.price = ?
                WHERE  cpigp.customer_group_id = ?
                AND cpigp.entity_id = ?";
    $connection->query($sql_price_one, array($newPrice1, 5, $entity_id));

    $sql_price_two = "UPDATE " . _getTableName('catalog_product_index_group_price') . "  cpigp
                SET  cpigp.price = ?
                WHERE  cpigp.customer_group_id = ?
                AND cpigp.entity_id = ?";
    $connection->query($sql_price_two, array($newPrice2, 6, $entity_id));

    $sql_price_four = "UPDATE " . _getTableName('catalog_product_index_group_price') . " cpigp 
                SET  cpigp.price = ?
                WHERE  cpigp.customer_group_id = ?
                AND cpigp.entity_id = ?";
    $connection->query($sql_price_four, array($newPrice4, 7, $entity_id));

    $sql_price_five = "UPDATE " . _getTableName('catalog_product_index_group_price') . " cpigp 
                SET  cpigp.price = ?
                WHERE  cpigp.customer_group_id = ?
                AND cpigp.entity_id = ?";
    $connection->query($sql_price_five, array($newPrice5, 8, $entity_id));


/*  catalog_product_index_price table */

    $sql_price_one = "UPDATE " . _getTableName('catalog_product_index_price') . " cpip 
                SET  cpip.group_price = ?
                WHERE  cpip.customer_group_id = ?
                AND cpip.entity_id = ?";
    $connection->query($sql_price_one, array($newPrice1, 5, $entity_id));

    $sql_price_two = "UPDATE " . _getTableName('catalog_product_index_price') . "  cpip
                SET  cpip.group_price = ?
                WHERE  cpip.customer_group_id = ?
                AND cpip.entity_id = ?";
    $connection->query($sql_price_two, array($newPrice2, 6, $entity_id));

    $sql_price_four = "UPDATE " . _getTableName('catalog_product_index_price') . " cpip 
                SET  cpip.group_price = ?
                WHERE  cpip.customer_group_id = ?
                AND cpip.entity_id = ?";
    $connection->query($sql_price_four, array($newPrice4, 7, $entity_id));

    $sql_price_five = "UPDATE " . _getTableName('catalog_product_index_price') . " cpip 
                SET  cpip.group_price = ?
                WHERE  cpip.customer_group_id = ?
                AND cpip.entity_id = ?";
    $connection->query($sql_price_five, array($newPrice5, 8, $entity_id));




/*  catalog_product_index_price_tmp table */

        $sql_price_one = "UPDATE " . _getTableName('catalog_product_index_price_tmp') . " cpipt 
                SET  cpipt.group_price = ?
                WHERE  cpipt.customer_group_id = ?
                AND cpipt.entity_id = ?";
    $connection->query($sql_price_one, array($newPrice1, 5, $entity_id));

    $sql_price_two = "UPDATE " . _getTableName('catalog_product_index_price_tmp') . "  cpipt
                SET  cpipt.group_price = ?
                WHERE  cpipt.customer_group_id = ?
                AND cpipt.entity_id = ?";
    $connection->query($sql_price_two, array($newPrice2, 6, $entity_id));

    $sql_price_four = "UPDATE " . _getTableName('catalog_product_index_price_tmp') . " cpipt 
                SET  cpipt.group_price = ?
                WHERE  cpipt.customer_group_id = ?
                AND cpipt.entity_id = ?";
    $connection->query($sql_price_four, array($newPrice4, 7, $entity_id));

    $sql_price_five = "UPDATE " . _getTableName('catalog_product_index_price_tmp') . " cpipt 
                SET  cpipt.group_price = ?
                WHERE  cpipt.customer_group_id = ?
                AND cpipt.entity_id = ?";
    $connection->query($sql_price_five, array($newPrice5, 8, $entity_id));
```